# can't access env['api.endpoint'] in grape middleware

Tags: api, ruby-grape

here use Grape write API function. and I want throttling API (API rate limit).

lib/grape/extensions/grape_extension.rb

```
module Grape
  module Extension
    module ThrottleExtension
      def throttle(options={})
        route_setting :throttle, options
        options
      end
      Grape::API.extend self
    end
  end
end
```

lib/grape/middleware/throttle_middleware.rb

```
module Grape
  module Middleware
    class ThrottleMiddleware < Grape::Middleware::Base
      def before
        binding.pry
      end
    end
  end
end
```

lib/grape_throttle.rb

```
require 'grape'
require 'grape/extensions/throttle_extension'
module Grape
  module Middleware
    autoload :ThrottleMiddleware, 'grape/middleware/grape_middleware'
  end
end
```

last, in `config/application.rb`

```
require File.expand_path('../../lib/grape_throttle', __FILE__)
config.middleware.use Grape::Middleware::ThrottleMiddleware
```

and, when I run with `rails s`,and call the api, the binding.pry has called.

```
[1] pry(#<Grape::Middleware::ThrottleMiddleware>)> env['api.endpoint']
=> nil
```

I want to know how i can access env['api.endpoint'] in Grape middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You can access env by::

```js
endpoint = @env["api.endpoint"]
```

I have tried this in a non-rails application and it worked.
You get all details of api endpoint in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a few years old but, we had this issue on production today and it was because the "content-type" in the header was not set to "application/json". Check that against what your sending in your request.

I have not been able to figure out why but I was also able to comment out our `use :<middleware_name>` in the `Grape::API`, and I immediately got a `"error": "The requested content-type 'text/plain' is not supported."` from grapes middleware.